# Something went wrong. Newbie error

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.jonathan.test01;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


    public class Test01Surface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = true;

    public Test01Surface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunning){
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid());
                continue;

            Canvas drawing = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            drawing.drawRGB(72, 98, 198);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(drawing);
        }

    }
}
```

I've been getting an Unreachable statement error at the line `Canvas drawing = ourHolder.lockCanvas();` 
I'm just following a tutorial video in Programming Android Applications. Please help me remove this error. I'm thinking that I should change the `continue;` statement to something else but since I'm new I don't know what to change it to. Or maybe the cause of the error is something else?

Answer (score 1):

remove the `;` at the end of this line:

```
if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid());
```

Answer (score 0):

`continue;` is always called and `Canvas drawing = ourHolder.lockCanvas();` is unreachable because you have a `";"` at the end of the if statement

Answer (score 0):

As already said by Jens the fault is the `;` at the end of your if statement.

For better readability of your code make it like this: also like this you probably won't do this fault again.

```
if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
  continue;
}
```